# Fontawesome resource plugin error

Tags: grails, font-awesome-4

I want to use `fontawesome` plugin in `grails`.
I have added in build config compile `:font-awesome-resources:4.0.3.1` to add plugin.I have added

```
customBootstrap 
{ 
   dependsOn 'font-awesome'         
   resource url: 'css/bootstrap.css'        
   resource url: 'js/bootstrap.js' resource url: 'css/bootstrap-fixtaglib.css'    
}
```

in `applicationresource.groovy` but when i run the application get error

> ERROR resource.ResourceProcessor  - Unable to load resources Message: No such property: pluginManager for class: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.Please provide solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is a configuration issue with migration from earlier grails versions or if font-awesome has not been migrated completely to grails 2.4.x. But I encountered this as well.

As a short (**dirty**) workaround, you can replace the code that causes the problem directly on the plugin.

File (**replace X with your project name**):

```
~/.grails/2.4.2/projects/X/plugins/font-awesome-resources-4.0.3.1/grails-app/conf/FontAwesomePluginResources.groovy
```

Replace lines 3 and 4 with:

```
def pluginManager = grails.util.Holders.pluginManager
def lesscssPlugin = pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('lesscss-resources') || pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('less-resources')
```

And give it a go.